# how to insert and update using PDO prepared method

Tags: php, sql, pdo, prepared-statement

.

**Is the following a good method to insert/update SQL data ?**

**Connection**

```
try{
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=5243c5435", "235v456234c5", "$23#4%34#54^");
    // Set the PDO error mode to exception
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . $e->getMessage());
}
```

**Insert Query**

```
try{
    // Prepare an insert statement
   $sql = "INSERT INTO members (name, email) VALUES (:name, :email)";
   $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

   // Bind parameters to statement
   $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
   $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);

   $name = "Hermione";
   $email = "hermionegranger@mail.com";
   $stmt->execute();
```

**Update Query**

```
try{
    // Prepare an insert statement
    $sql = "UPDATE members SET name=:name, email=:email WHERE phone = :phone" or die("Prepare Error");
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    
    // Bind parameters to statement
    $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':phone', $whatsapp, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    
    $phone="1234567890";
    $name = "Hermione";
    $email = "hermionegranger@mail.com";
    $stmt->execute();
```

I need suggestions from experts, is it efficient and safe to use above to codes ?

Comment: define "good", "efficient", and "safe". These are subjective terms, to an extent. It's protected from SQL injection, certainly. That's about as much as we can say really.

Comment: `die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . $e->getMessage());` isn't very secure though...you shouldn't explicitly output exception details to the display, as it could leak sensitive details by accident. Just configure PHP to handle all exceptions - either it can log them to the display (in development and testing environments) or to a file (in a live environment). There's not really any need to catch the exception specifically.

Comment: As for "efficiency", there's nothing shown here which is likely to specifically cause performance problems, if that's what you mean. It's bog-standard, boiler-plate PDO code, nothing unusual.

Comment: The code is basically all right but there us too much cargo cult code that needs to be removed. That " or die" part makes absolutely no sense. All try and catch statements must be also removed. There can be other improvements too, like sending data into execute() instead of using bindParam.